# no additional driver

Tags: drivers, nvidia

I installed ubuntu 11.04 with wubi on win 7, I upgrade it to 13.04. every I Upgrade my system from to 11.04 - 13.04 never see my additional driver detect my GT540 Nvidia Card.I am only use internal graphics processor.anyone have solution?

Comment: System Settings > Software & updates > Additional Drivers

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with my GTX 470.

1. Grab the software package Additonal Drivers.
2. Open the Software Sources application and the drivers will show up.